# Pydantic model. Serializing with excluded fields

Tags: python, caching, serialization, deserialization, pydantic

I am using Pydantic 2.0+
First of all, my main goal is to cache Pydantic objects into the Redis.

It must be some universal function (wrapper/decorator of course) that receives any existing Pydantic object and cache it into the Redis.

I did not find any modern suitable packages for this, so s made a simple solution: serialized pydantic object into the json, wrote it to the Redis and read and then deserialized it into the Pydantic object.

Below is a simple example (redis excluded for simplicity).

So far so good... But I started to use computed fields and need to hide some source fields (Field(exclude=True)).
And I did not found any solution to dump model with all excluded fields :(

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, computed_field


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    hidden_field: str = Field(exclude=True, default=None)

    @computed_field
    def visible_upper(self) -> str:
        try:
            return self.hidden_field.upper()
        except:
            return ""


my_obj = MyModel(name="foo", hidden_field="bar")

print("Before serialization:", my_obj.visible_upper)

my_dump = my_obj.model_dump_json(include=[field for field in my_obj.model_fields])

my_obj = MyModel.model_validate_json(my_dump)

print("After serialization:", my_obj.visible_upper)
```

Output:

```
Before serialization: BAR
After serialization:
```

So I am a little frustrated. Is there some good and modern package for caching Pydantic objects or mey be it is simpler to find solution for my code above to work?

Thank you. Sorry if my English or python level is not enough :)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that serialize pydantic objects through the model_dump/model_validate is not a good idea because some of this:
https://blog.devgenius.io/deserialize-child-classes-with-pydantic-that-gonna-work-784230e1cf83

So I guess to use Pickle for such case and all is works great! )
Pickle normally process my pydantic object and all nested pydantic objects etc...

Only when I need to create dynamic model, I must to do it with **module** parameter like this:

```
LangText = create_model(
    "LangText",
    __module__=__name__,  # for Pickling
    **{lang.key: (str, "") for lang in labels_iso639_3},  # dynamically created fields
)
```